# wpf legacy server call

Tags: wpf, legacy

We have a legacy application running tomcat that publishes data in a simple html table.
I have no control on the remote server publishing the data.
I am looking to extract the data into a WPF desktop application and display it as a table.

**Is there any way a WPF application can make a url call, get the result and parse the data.
This would be similar to AJAX from JSP.**

Any thoughts/ideas? Please advice.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a WPF question (as that's just the mechanism to display the information once you've retrieved and parsed it).

You could use something like [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) to open the URL and retrieve the data, then write some code to parse the HTML and then you can use WPF to finally display it any way you like.

Comment: probably the reason i got nothing when i searched ajax with WPF. I was able to use HTTPWebRequest to open url and retrieve the data. Needed to use default proxy to get the information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a web service proxy class if the service is SOAP or use the WebClient class to request the data.

Once you get the data, use LINQ to parse it.

To get a more specific answer, you need to make your question more specific.

Comment: This one might work too but I need to try this. I was in a hurry so choose the first approach that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the condition of the HTML that you're receiving from the legacy application.

If it's XHTML, it can be parsed by an XML parser, and you can use the `WebClient` class to retrieve it from the server and LINQ or the `XmlDocument` to parse and query the data returned./

If it's not well-formed XML, you'll need to use an HTML parser to parse it, which probably means that you'll want to use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Of course, you may not need to parse it at all.  You might be able to get away with simply using a `WebBrowser` control to display it.  It all depends on your requirements.